# NLog.config -> Deleting old logfiles possible?

Tags: nlog

I have a question about the Nlog.config. I am not able to delete old logfiles

Here is what i tried first with this NLog.config:

```
<target name="asyncFileError" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
  <target name="file"  xsi:type="File" 
        layout="${date:format=dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss.mmm} ${level} ${logger} ${message} - ${exception:format=tostring} [${callsite}]"
        fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/xyz/Logs/${shortdate}/LogFile.log"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        createDirs="true" />
</target>
```

This saves a log per day(and expands it) in a folder with the current date.
e.g.:

```
Logs  
   ->2018-06-05
      -> LogFile.log     
   ->2018-06-06
      -> LogFile.log
   ->2018-06-07
      -> LogFile.log
   ->2018-06-08
      -> LogFile.log
```

I want NLog now, to cleanup the Logs-folder so only the folders and logs are kept from the last three days.

Therefore i read the NLog documentation and found solutions on stack overflow (which i already tried out), which copy the logfiles to an archive directory. But this isn't actually what i had in mind.

I want to keep my folder structure and just want to get rid of old logs by NLog. 
Is there any way, i can force NLog to discard o logs older than x-days?

As an example, i want NLog to cleanup the Log-folder on 2018-06-09 like this

```
Logs  
   ->2018-06-07
      -> LogFile.log
   ->2018-06-08
      -> LogFile.log
   ->2018-06-09
      -> LogFile.log
```

... which means that on 2018-06-09 these folders and logs are gone:

```
   ->2018-06-05
      -> LogFile.log     
   ->2018-06-06
      -> LogFile.log
```

We are currently using NLog 4.4.12.

Thanks in advance for any ideas and tips.

Regards,
Maurice

EDIT:
There's no problem in giving up the date-folders and rename the Logfiles with the date. So if this could help finding a solution.

Comment: NLog does not support recursive log-cleanup in sub-folders. I recommend upgrading to NLog 4.5 and stop using sub-folders. See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files

Comment: I got it to work with the version of Nlog we currently use (i'll upgrade it anyway) with your tips. I have tried it before like this but it didn't work. Maybe because i tried to get the date in the logfile name as the docs say it won't work with that. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Seems like i got it to work without subfolders:

```
<target name="asyncFileError" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
  <target name="file"  xsi:type="File" 
        layout="${date:format=dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss.mmm} ${level} ${logger} ${message} - ${exception:format=tostring} [${callsite}]"
        fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/xyz/Logs/LogFile.log"
        archiveFileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/xyz/Logs/Archive/Log.{#####}.log"
        archiveAboveSize="10024000"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        maxArchiveFiles="10"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        createDirs="true" />
</target>
```

This moves the logfiles to the archive every day or if they exceed the 10024000 bytes. And the archive keeps the last 10 files (maybe the customer should tinker with the max files if he wants to).

I lost the date in the filename but hey... you can still see the changed date in the filesystem or open the log to see the logdate. I think you'll have to lose something in this game :P.

Thx @Rolf Kristensen